# Программа продолжает работать после необработанного исключения

Tags: java, swing, исключения

У меня есть вот такой класс:

```
private class MyThread extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    private MultidimensionalSolver solver;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        manager.getInfoPanel().setVisible(true);
        solver = new MultidimensionalSolver(manager.getTask());
        while (!solver.isSolutionFind() && flag) {
            solver.findSolution();
            manager.getTask().setSolution(
                    solver.getSolution().getSolution());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void done() {
        //setSolution();
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    private void setSolution() {
        manager.getInfoLabel().setText(solver.getSolution().toGuiString());
        if (!manager.getTable().isTableSoluted()) {
            manager.getTable().addLastColumn();
            manager.getRowTable().addSolutionRow();
        }
        manager.getRowTable().updateUi();
    }
}
```

В методе setSolution() у меня происходил выброс исключения. Что было очевиднее я генерирую в методе done() исключение специально. Дальше очень странное поведение происходит. Я нигде не обрабатываю исключение. Swing worker у меня запускается здесь:

```
private void callSolver() {
    manager.getStop().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            flag = false;
        }
    });
    thread = new MyThread();
    thread.execute();
}
```

Этот метод вызывается здесь:

```
@Override
protected void createOkAction() {
    if (withEdit.isSelected()) {
        manager.getTask().setSolutionEditable(true);
    } else {
        manager.getTask().setSolutionEditable(false);
    }
    callSolver();
}
```

А он в свою очередь здесь:

```
protected JButton createOkButton(){
    JButton ok = new JButton("ok");
    ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            createOkAction();
            frame.dispose();
        }
    });
    return ok;
}
```

То есть это обработчик кнопки.
Как можно видеть, исключение я нигде не обрабатываю. Но после вылета этого исключения происходит stacktrace и программа не вываливается! Я могу спокойно продолжать работать с GUI, как ни в чем не бывало. Из-за чего может такое поведение происходить? Я подозреваю что это может быть связано с тем, что добавив SwingWorker-а программа стала многопоточной

Comment: Надо внимательным быть с много-поточностью в свинге. Хорошо изучить эту тему. Обычно всякие GUI, и свинг в том числе, не любят, не признают много-поточность. Но имеются методы для передачи выполнения в поток GUI. В свинге точно должны быть такие возможности. Если другой поток хочет изменить что-то в GUI, то он должен передать свои хотелки в поток GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class NullPointerException extends RuntimeException
```

Данное исключение является `unchecked`, при его возникновении в другом потоке и если оно не обрабатывается, то будет использован [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) по умолчанию, который просто выведет в консоль stack trace. Выполнение потока соответствено будет прервано.

Comment: Точно! Тот поток, в котором исключение сгенерировалось - он то вылетает. А по скольку GUI рисуется в другом потоке - в нем можно продолжать спокойно работать. Спасибо!